# Matlab output format that Python can consume

Tags: python, json, matlab, csv

I am pretty new to Matlab but relatively familiar with Python. I am now using an existing Matlab code but I want the the program to generate output that Python can consume. The standard output format, as far as I know is `.mat`, which is more like a binary format.

Another function I considered is the built-in `csvwrite` but the problem with that is the variable I want to output  is more like a dictionary and it can have several level subfield (e.g., `feature.subfeature.subsubfeature = [1, 2, 3]`). Another possibility is to output `json` format but it seems there is no built-in method for output `json`. There are some toolbox I can use but I don't have `sudo` permission on the machine that I am using.

Any suggestion on what's a better way to output a format that python can consume? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution with the least effort on MATLAB side would be to use SciPy, which read/write mat-files:

[SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html)

The mat-format is binary, but (surprisingly) open and document by Mathworks.